# Prevent to Infer as Union Type

Tags: typescript

I'm now trying to implement a small type-safe coordinate management in TypeScript.
It manages origin of coordinate as type parameter. And these function expects only one origin type.

Here is small example code.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2&ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgSwOYIHZQLxQEQBMD2AxgK4C2Eqw2UAPjgDYCGI+xwAtAG4IQDuY+OFVo5uAZ2KN6XHv0FUA3ACg0wCHABmjQtADC+QbjSM1AHhhQIADzWpcY2IhSoAfFADeSqFCsAuKKhkAEbqyt4g-oGkIXDKAL5KShrEqITACPjoWkIAFhBiwOaWNhT2jshoLgAUAHR1hAZwRqgm+f76hsZmMC4A2gC6AJTtjc2t5m6e3gD001B1NUoJSg2oBVCEAIwjnS1m2EwsbDJ8AkLYbljuPv6bADRQEVCbUHHKq+uEAEw7TV0QpgOzFYHG4p3kF0wHhuzweTy+r3emU+AGZfmN9gQSORKJCrjD7o9-CjEYkPsAoBoXlhssA8gUqlsHt9BspZpSXggHGgNOo4BBcFBGA4On89gCgUdQbIzlQXGTkRSNAiaYxcvlgIzCYQUaylOzlVAuUbULy4PzBcKoKKMRKsWQKMI6JKQSc5Od5UA)

```js
type Origin = "document" | "layout-viewport" | "visual-viewport";
interface Coordinate<O extends Origin> {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

function farthest<O extends Origin>(...coordinates: Coordinate<O>[]): Coordinate<O> {
  // ...
}

const c1: Coordinate<"layout-viewport"> = { x: 1, y: 1 };
const c2: Coordinate<"layout-viewport"> = { x: 1, y: 2 };
const c3: Coordinate<"document"> = { x: 1, y: 3 };

const f1 = farthest(c1, c2);
// f1 is inferred as Coordinate<"layout-viewport">

const f2 = farthest(c1, c3);
// f2 is inferred as Coordinate<"document" | "layout-viewport">
```

I want error in `f2` because I expect `farthest` function accepts only one origin type.

How to write type definition of `farthest` function to prevent to infer as union type?

Comment: typescript is a [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/structural-typing)

Comment: Please [edit] your code so that `Coordinate<O>` depends structurally on `O`.  Right now `O` is completely unused, which [leads to weird behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  At best this distracts from your question, at worst it makes your problem invalid.  If I hand you a variable of type `Coordinate<"document">`, how could you tell it apart from a variable of type `Coordinate<"layout-viewport">` at runtime?  If it's impossible, it's not clear why you need TS to do so.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your comment.  In current situation with this code, the origins are not used in runtime because these coords are from DOM API like `getClientRects` and `{ x: visualViewport.offsetLeft, ... }`, not from user input or external component.. I want to prevent to mix these coords from different origins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It manages origin of coordinate as type parameter.
> And these function expects only one origin type.

The problem is the `O` parameter is not used in `Coordinate`, whence there is in fact no distinction between those instantiations.

Here is how to make it work, but of course it is quite ugly, since with an interface there is no constructor to leverage in order not to have to repeat that label (see the code below).

So, I think this is a case where you either might want a concrete class, or maybe distinct non-overlapping interfaces that implement `Coordinate` (so sub-types) might do...  I should play with it.  Please feel free to let me know (with a comment) what of that sounds reasonable if you would like me to try and provide a more specific solution.

```
type Origin = "document" | "layout-viewport" | "visual-viewport";

interface Coordinate<O extends Origin> {
  _o: O;
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

function farthest<O extends Origin, C extends Coordinate<O>>(...cs: C[]): C {
  throw "NOT YET IMPLEMENTED";
}

const c1: Coordinate<"layout-viewport"> = { _o: "layout-viewport", x: 1, y: 1 };
const c2: Coordinate<"layout-viewport"> = { _o: "layout-viewport", x: 1, y: 2 };
const c3: Coordinate<"document"> = { _o: "document", x: 1, y: 3 };

const f1 = farthest(c1, c2);  // OK: f1 is Coordinate<"layout-viewport">

const f2 = farthest(c1, c3);  // ERROR!
// Type '"document"' is not assignable to type '"layout-viewport"'.
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgSwOYIHZQLxQEQBMD2AxgK4C2Eqw2UAPjgDYCGI%20xwAtAG4IQDuY%20OFVo5uAZ2KN6XHv0FUA3ACglaYBDgAzRoWgBhfINxpG6gDwwoEAB7rUuMbEQpUAPigBvJVCgB9fABcsMo%201kGoZABGGiFQIOFRMUoAviqaxKiEwAj46NpCABYQYsAWVrYUDk7IaAA0UHrldlUGRibmMK6uABQAdP2EYkF6ANoAugCUw57eUMAFcPi8OAByMAAqUACaAKKbAJIAsgAKADI7hzsr6zsAItjKqUqEuSVQhACMw4ZwxqimEDM2CYLDYMj4AiE2HcWA8fkCDGYrA43Ah8mw9TCUA%209Xi2KgyWUL1Qb0IACZvm1-uZgUiwai5FCYZ54UFaaCUbJIVRMUEcXEgmSCUTXsB3gBmSm-dqAvBEMgUKjMuH%20NkEEjkSgYqBY-l48XClTEt6aD6YKD5ebFYDdT71ckTBQ%20AD0ztgAGkgqaoAhHK1pdTZSDkeDGUqjaKLUKsJaiiVbfzCOLHS63TsAErpmDpgCESldUHW4GgAHI5RrFdgSz7HKh8GLGGIxMh-pF6NBgPg5sWoGXg-SueiS70lEA)